# Why do Flutter StatefulWidget subclasses need to override the default constructor?

Tags: flutter

Why do the Flutter code examples always override the default contructor but don't add anything new to it?

If the overridden constructor code just calls `super`, can't they NOT override the constructor and inherit the default constructor's behavior? The default constructor can handle the `key` parameter anyway.

e.g., https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example

```dart
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  Demo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  DemoState createState() => DemoState();
}
```

In other words, the above code should function the same as this code:

```dart
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  DemoState createState() => DemoState();
}
```

because the default implementation of StatefulWidget already has the constructor:

```dart
abstract class StatefulWidget extends Widget {
  const StatefulWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is important to override the constructor, here is why:

In your example, try doing this:

```
Demo demo = Demo(key: myKey);
```

If you didn't declare a constructor, this will throw an error, because you never told Demo that you wanted to be able to pass a key into it. Worse yet, look at this example

```
class MyParentClass {
  MyParentClass({required this.value});

  int value;
}

class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass {
}
```

If you try to make a new object of type MyChildClass, what will value be? You will get an error, in fact you won't even be able to compile this example, dart will complain that `MyParentClass` doesn't have a default constructor before you even compile. Because you told `MyChildClass` that it was ok to receive no arguments, but you told `MyParentClass`that it should always receive at least one.

What if you had a class of nullable values and you wanted an inherited class to always start with null on those values? if the constructor was automatically inherited, it would be impossible to do this.

This sadly means that if you have a class with say, 10 variables, and you want to inherit from it, you will have to declare a constructor for all of those values again.

Back to StatefulWidget key terms, it is not a huge deal if you don't override your stateful widgets constructor, as key is nullable, if you don't intend to ever assign a key to your widget, it is ok to ignore creating a constructor, specially if you don't have any other value to pass to it. But remember that the reason why this is the case is because StatefulWidget understands that key will sometimes be null.